# How to Export the GetFolderContent $ rootFolder value in CSV file using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake

I have been trying to find out the way to export the list of Folders in CSV file to Azure DataLake Directly . I have found a Powershell shell toolkit snipet code and trying to export . but could not find out the way . Pls help!
below is the line am trying to export

GetFolderContent $rootFolder

Comment: I'm a little confused, you want to "write the list of Folders and subfolders to csv file from Azure Datalake " or "export the list of Folders in CSV file to Azure DataLake "?

Comment: @Ivan Yang - I want to to list all the folders and subfolders from Azure Datalake to CSV using powershell

Comment: is there any special format in the csv file, or if just one column?

Comment: Just one column for the Folder path Eg : /Hello/Sample/AA like this

Comment: for the folder path, do you mean this "adl://xxx.azuredatalakestore.net/cc1/cc2"?

Comment: function GetFolderContent
{
    Param([string]$rootFolder)
    $items = Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItem -Account $dataLakeStoreName -Path $rootFolder
    Write-Host "$rootFolder"  
   foreach ($item in $items)
    {if ($item.Type -eq "DIRECTORY")
        {$nextFolder = $item.Name        
         if ($rootFolder -eq "\")
            {GetFolderContent $nextFolder              
            }else{GetFolderContent $rootFolder/$nextFolder}     
        }     
    }
    return $null    
}
$dataLakeStoreName = "" 
$rootFolder = "/" 
GetFolderContent $rootFolder This is code i use .

Comment: Above code gives me correct output . how will i write all these in CSV file is my question . Used Export-CSV but not helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly output to the csv file, the code below works at side:

```
function GetFolderContent 
{
 Param(
 [string]$rootFolder
 )

  $items = Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItem -Account "xxx" -Path $rootFolder
   Write-Host "$rootFolder" 
   $rootFolder >> "d:\test\222.csv"

   foreach ($item in $items) 
   {
     if ($item.Type -eq "DIRECTORY") 
     {
        $nextFolder = $item.Name 

         if ($rootFolder -eq "\") 
         {
           GetFolderContent $nextFolder 
         }
         else
         {
           GetFolderContent $rootFolder/$nextFolder
         }
     }
   }
      return $null 
} 


   $rootFolder = "/" 

   GetFolderContent $rootFolder
```